# Using For Comprehension in Scala to only flatMap Future[T] after an If Test

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I need help using an if statement that should only be run if the test is false in a for-comprehension dealing with futures. I am new to scala and using [this blog post](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) as my guide.

The code is

```
  for {
      emptyResults: Boolean = areResultsEmpty(content)
      resp <- getResp(content) if !emptyResults
      } yield resp
```

If `emptyResults` is true then the `getResp()` throws an error, but in the above, `getResp()` gets run even when `emptyResults` is true. How do I make sure that the `getResp()` only gets run if `emptyResults` is false?

I have also tried writing the if statement like below but that throws an error `error: value map is not a member of Any`

```
  acmResp <- if (!emptyResults) {
    getResp(content)
  }
```

I have looked over other solutions here including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949785/scalas-for-comprehension-if-statements) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949785/scalas-for-comprehension-if-statements) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192227/how-can-i-do-if-else-inside-a-for-comprehension) but they haven't helped with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for` comprehension is "syntactic sugar." Which means that before it is translated into byte code it is first translated into a different, standard, language construct.

In this case you have a generator, `<-`, and a guard, `if ...`. That will be translated to a `map()` call and a `withFilter()` call. So, you see, you can't prevent the generator from executing by adding a guard condition. A guard can only act as a filter for what gets passed to the `yield`.

To get what you want you'll have to move the condition test outside of the `for` comprehension, and at that point it's easier to just make it a simple `map()`.

```
val result = if (areResultsEmpty(content)) {
                . . . //some default
             } else {
                getResp(content).map(/*do work*/)
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the call to `areResultsEmpty` a guard in the comprehension expression.

```
for {
  resp <- getResp(content) if !areResultsEmpty(content)
} yield resp
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign before any generators in a for comprehension.

```
for {
  emptyResults: Boolean = areResultsEmpty(content) // Not allowed
  resp <- getResp(content) if !emptyResults
} yield resp
```

Instead try something like:

```
if(!areResultsEmpty(content)) {
  for {
      resp <- getResp(content)
  } yield resp
}
else {
  ...
}
```